# EF Core OrderBy Count of References on other Table

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a table with authors and a table with books.

```
public class Author
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

I want to order my Authors by the amount of Books they have.
I need to Access the data via `_context.Authors.XXX` as I have additional filtering applied on the `IQueryable`.

I am using net5.0 and ef core 5.0.

Is there an 'elegant' way?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a `Books` nav property, `_context.Authors.OrderByDescending(x => x.Books.Count());`

Comment: That was it. Thank you!

Comment: Moved to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Books` nav property and map accordingly, something named like:

```
public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

Then in your query:

```
_context.Authors.OrderByDescending(x => x.Books.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update both your Author and Book classes.
The author class needs to include a navigational "Books" property which will hold a list of books by the Author, while the Book class will hold an AuthorId property which will serve as a foreign key to the Author table.

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AuthorID {get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public Author() {
       this.Books = new List<Book>();
    }
    
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it was enough to add a `public List<Book> Books { get; set; }` to the `Author` class. Thanks for the answer though!